# I just want to convert an excel created using Openpyxl , I want to store data inside a database using sqlite3. And below is my code

Tags: python, excel, sqlite, openpyxl

My task is to create an excel file manually using openpyxl and I want to insert data into a database created using sqlite3. My logical approach is push the contents of the data inside an empty list and push it into a database using sqlite3.

```
import openpyxl
import sqlite3
xlsheet=openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet=xlsheet.active
sheet.title="xl_to_db"
    
    sheet['A1']="FirstName"
    sheet['B1']="LastName"
    sheet['C1']="Salary"
    sheet['D1']="Department"
    sheet['A2']="Aron"
    sheet['B2']="v"
    sheet['C2']="xxxxx"
    sheet['D2']="DS"
    sheet['A3']="paul"
    sheet['B3']='r'
    sheet['C3']="yyyyy"
    sheet['D3']="webdev"
    
    xlsheet.save('xl_to_db.xlsx')
    lt=[]
    xlsheet_read=openpyxl.load_workbook("xl_to_db.xlsx")
    xlsheet_read.active
    reader=xlsheet_read['xl_to_db']
    for row in range(1,reader.max_row+1):
        for column in range(1,reader.max_column+1):
            lt.append(reader.cell(row,column).value)
    n=4
    for i in range(0, len(lt),n):
        yes=[lt[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(lt), n)]
    print(yes)
    '''
    for i in range(len(yes)):
        inputt=yes[i]
        print(inputt)
    s=str(inputt)'''
    
update_xl=sqlite3.connect("xl_to_db.db")
ex=update_xl.execute('''create table if not exists Employee_table(f_name,l_name,salary,dept)''')
updated_xl='''INSERT INTO (f_name,l_name,salary,dept) VALUES (?,?,?,?)'''
update_xl.execute(updated_xl,yes)
update_xl.commit()
update_xl.close()
```

Error message:

> update_xl.execute(updated_xl,yes) sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(":
> syntax error

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I haven't given the table name in the insert statement... :)